# I want the azure-ad-b2c users to access my company's application with restricted access

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a sitecore application (version 9.0) hosted in azure. I have an azure ad synchronized with the on-premise ad consisting of internal users from my company. I have given full access to the internal users of my company on the sitecore applications.

I want to allow my b2c users from different domain to access the site core applications. the external users are from a separate azure ad. however, the external users will only have read-only permissions on the sitecore applications.

How to allow both the external and internal users to access the sitecore application hosted in azure?

Comment: Do you want to federate the internal users directly from Azure AD to Sitecore? Or can you federate them indirectly from Azure AD through Azure AD B2C to Sitecore?

Comment: I had already federated internal users from their azure ad to sitecore.

Comment: similarly i want to federate my external users to sitecore from their azure active directory

Comment: by external users I refer to the b2c users